# typeahead.js 1.2.0 version?

Tags: typeahead.js

I am using typeahead.js with Bootstrap 4, via the "typeaheadjs.css" filler.

A couple of months ago I realised that the version of typeahead.js I was using was old (v0.x) and that there was a much more recent version in a different repository (v1.2.0). I was chuffed as it seemed to work better and fix a lot of the issues I was having.

Today, I cannot for the life of me find that newer version again. The website I was looking at is pointing at the old version, as if I dreamt the whole thing... yet I have it on my server as evidence:

http://www.bdtheque.com/typeahead.js.1.2.0/typeahead.jquery.js

Looking in MY Git history, I see that the website I took the new version from changed from https://typeahead.js.org/ (which had the old one) to http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ (which had the more recent one), but today both websites feature the same old version.

I can't find ANYTHING on Google about a version 1.2.0.

Can anyone shed any light?

Cheers!

Comment: I think you may be stumbled upon this comment here https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/pull/1212#issuecomment-142922358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same difficulty.

It seems the old typeahead repo was abandoned in 2015. It was forked and is maintained here with latest 1.2 version:
https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js

Source:
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1676

Comment: Yes this is where I found it! How come I can't find this page via Google?! Anyway, thanks :)